Installation of a regular ceiling light where a ceiling fan was
New fixture has black, white and ground. The ceiling fixture has 2 sets of cables.  One is black, white, and ground. The other has black, red, white, and ground. I have tried every combo, the light comes on and will not turn off. How do I add images to this cry for help?

Hit the "Edit" button at the bottom left and then use the "mountain and sun" button in the editor toolbar to add your pictures

Do you have one switch (that controlled both the fan and its associated light) or two separate switches (one for the fan and one for the light)?  Or no switches (fan and light controlled just by the pull chains)?

The standard in the US is:

ground = green or bare
neutral = white
hot = black or red

In your case, the original circuit likely used a 4 wire cable with the black for the light and red for the fan, because it's ok that both of those circuits share a neutral and ground. Wire all matching colors (white to white, black to black, ground to ground) and cap off the red wire.
If you do this and the light still does not work, the switch may be wired incorrectly. The hot (black) wire should come into the switch's junction box, go through the switch, and exit out to the light. The neutral (white) should bypass the switch (unless it's a smart switch or dimmer).
Make sure not to mix up which switch is on the red wire and which is on the black wire.

The OP very well could have a switch loop of some sort...

In that case, wouldn't there be multiple wires in the junction for the fixture?

We don't know what the prior fixture wiring was
